# Testing to see if a text string is part of a variable

Tags: jquery

I'm setting a variable to the contents of a h1 tag on my site. I want to write an if statement which tests to see if there is a specific word inside that h1 tag. I need to set a dropdown based on the title of the form.

So, I have this html.

```
<div id="booking-details"><h1>This is Los Angeles</h1></div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
var city = $('#booking-details h1').text();
if (city.text().indexOf('Los Angeles') >= 0)) {alert("This city is Los Angeles")};
```

I'm getting a syntax error and not quite sure how to pull the index of the text from the variable.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `text()` twice, just do:

```
var city = $('#booking-details h1').text();
if (city.indexOf('Los Angeles') >= 0)) {alert("This city is Los Angeles")};
```

Or:

```
var city = $('#booking-details h1');
if (city.text().indexOf('Los Angeles') >= 0)) {alert("This city is Los Angeles")};
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, except I had an extra parenthesis in there which was causing the syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you can get the text() of the text().  Have you tried:

```
var city = $('#booking-details h1');
if (city.text().indexOf('Los Angeles') >= 0)) {alert("This city is Los Angeles")};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `city.text()` when you already set `city` to `$('#booking-details h1').text();`?

Use

```
var city = $('#booking-details h1');
if (city.text().indexOf('Los Angeles') >= 0)) {alert("This city is Los Angeles")};
```

Answer (score 0):

...I'm a bit late, but for others who'll find this via google, try the pure jQuery attempt:

HTML

```
 <div id="booking-details">
     <h1>The city of Los Angeles</h1>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
var city = 'Los Angeles';
if ($('#booking-details h1:contains("' + city + '")').text().length)
    alert('Welcome to ' + city);
```

[Test it on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/cMscm/)